# SQL duplicates with different primary keys

Tags: sql

I have a table in this form:

```
id | firstname | lastname
---+-----------+----------
1  | alex      | marti
2  | mark      | finger
3  | alex      | marti
4  | ted       | port
```

Need to return the `firstname`, `lastname` duplicates in this form:

```
1  | alex      | marti
3  | alex      | marti
```

I tried doing `select firstname, lastname from t group by firstname, lastname having count(*) > 1` but that will return something like

```
firstname | lastname
----------+----------
mark      | finger
alex      | marti
ted       | port
```

And I need the `id` of the duplicates but of course `select id, firstname, lastname from t group by id, firstname, lastname` won't work.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The currently accepted answer is limited, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019039/sql-duplicates-with-different-primary-keys/2019058#2019058 which is a _correct_ implementation. (Albeit not my preferred technique.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to aggregate the id. If you need only the ID of one of them, for, say, deletion, you could do:

```
select max(id) id, firstname, lastname from t group by firstname, lastname having count(*) > 1
```

If you want both id's and know there will never be more than 2, you could do the following:

```
select min(id) minid, max(id) maxid, firstname, lastname from t group by firstname, lastname having count(*) > 1
```

If you want all duplicates, along with their id's, you'll have to use a derived table, as in Nitin Midha's answer.

Comment: NO! #1 is clearly not what was asked, and #2 only supports 2 duplicates, yet it is trivial to obtain the information OP was asking for no matter how many duplicates.

Comment: i'll agree that #2 would rarely be applicable, but in cases where it is, that will give better performance than using a derived table, so i wanted to show that alternative as well. i'll trust OP to handle the judgement of whether or not it fits the description. as for #1: it may be true that it doesn't meet the exact requirements of the original question, but 9 out of 10 times when questions such as this one pops up, what is *wanted* (regardless of what is *asked for*) is a simple way to delete these duplicate items, and for that purpose, #1 will suffice a lot of the times.

Comment: (continued) i think you'll agree that actually helping the user is what this site is *really* all about; that will not always come down to simply answering the question, because the question may not be phrased just right. i provided a solution that i suspected would resolve the problems that Lucas was facing, and the accept button and the comment seems to indicate that it did indeed.

Answer (score 3):

```
select a.* from t a,
(select first, last from t group by first, last having count(*) > 1) b
where a.first = b.first and a.last = b.last
```

Comment: This is one of the ways to do it. Basically all the _correct_ solutions require you to join a result set of duplicates (on first name, last name) back to the original table.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Id, First_Name, Last_Name
FROM
(
Select Id, First_Name, Last_Name,
Count() Over (Partition By First_Name,Last_Name) Count
From Emp
) AS T
Where T.Count > 1
```

Comment: I'm certain that this is non-standard SQL

Comment: Use of Analytical Functions, which comes with SQL 2005 and above.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, firstname, lastname
from table t
where exists (select 1
from table t2
where t2.firstname = t.firstname
and t2.lastname = t.lastname
and t2.id <> t.id)
```

Comment: This one also works nicely... Basically select any rows where you can find any duplicate with a different ID.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and this is what I did to resolve it.
First I identified the dups with the following query:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) as num, ID, Firstname, Lastname FROM TableA GROUP BY ID, Firstname, Lastname;
```

Then I created a temp table.  called TempTableA
Which had the same columns as TableA and extra Column called Dups, you will see why further.

then I did the following insert:

```
INSERT INTO TempTableA(Dups, ID, Firstname, Lastname) SELECT COUNT(*) as num, ID, Firstname, Lastname FROM TableA GROUP BY ID, Firstname, Lastname having count(*)>=1;
```

By now you might know why we added an extra column called dups. anywho..

After that I did the following delete statement:

```
DELETE FROM TableA Where ID NOT IN (SELECT t.ID  FROM TempTableA t);
```

And presto that did the work for me remove the rest of the dups.

Its not a one step process but it did do the job right.

NOTE: you need to change the tableA to the correct name that you have as well as the column names in order for it to work.
Let me know if you run into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
--Remove Duplicate Rows with different ID SQL SERVER

CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    Id        int,
    Firstname varchar(20),
    Lastname  varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable( Id, Firstname, Lastname) SELECT min(Id)as Id, Firstname, Lastname 
FROM UserTable 
GROUP BY  Firstname, Lastname

delete from UserTable where Id not in(select Id from #TempTable)

drop #TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following to show all the **id** column values

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id SEPARATOR ',') AS ids, firstname, lastname FROM t GROUP BY firstname, lastname HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This should show something like this:

```
ids | firstname | lastname
----+-----------+----------
1,3 | alex      | marti
```