# Deleting Duplicates using C#

Tags: c#, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL duplicates with different primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019039/sql-duplicates-with-different-primary-keys)

My query returns all duplicates in gridview.  However, when I select one record from a duplicate, both are removed. When I use a straight select on all users in userlist the delete option will remove only the row selected.  I suspect when I select a record from the dup it is using the selectcommand and therefore grabbing both primary keys.

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [PKEY], [user] FROM [userlist]
            WHERE LogonName IN (
                SELECT [user]
                FROM [userlist]
                GROUP BY [user]
                HAVING (COUNT([user]) > 1))"
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [userlist] WHERE [PKEY] = @PKEY" >
```

Adding code behind for checkbox, which works when using straight select:

```
if (checkbox.Checked)
            {
                int PKEY = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
                SqlDataSource1.DeleteParameters["PKEY"].DefaultValue = PKEY.ToString();
                SqlDataSource1.Delete();
            }
```

Comment: Is there anything unique about each row or are they exact duplicates ?

Comment: Please don't put tag information in the title. StackOverflow has a very effective tag system that categorizes questions all by itself; the system even knows how to properly feed that information to Google. Use the tags properly by entering them in the `tags` area of your question instead of the title, and use the extra space in the title to improve the question itself. Thanks.

Comment: This helped.  I used a different query.

possible duplicate of SQL duplicates with different primary keys – Cocowalla

Comment: Your query is bad.  You are comparing loginname to user from the same table.  Change your inner query to (select logonname.....)

Answer (score 0):

You must return `PrimaryKey` on your `gridView.` and when you delete you pass your selected primarykey;

You must ensure that PKEY is defined as PrimaryKey, in your DataBase on your table

You can also add DISTINCT to your query,

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
```

Comment: Yes, PKEY is primary key in the SQL table
`SqlDataSource1.DeleteParameters["PKEY"].DefaultValue = PKEY.ToString();`
`SqlDataSource1.Delete();`

Comment: DataKeyNames="PKEY" is in my gridview.  I need to return the duplicates so the user can see which one to remove.

Answer (score 0):

If you can choose an arbitrary record, an easy way to delete every record but one for each group is take the MAX of the primary key and delete all others:

```
DELETE FROM [userlist]
WHERE PKEY NOT IN (
    SELECT MAX(PKEY) pkey
    FROM [userlist]
    GROUP BY [user]
    )
```